# Toggling Mapbox GL Control Visibility

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a React app with an instance of a Mapbox GL map inside a container that I am allowing my users to adjust the width and height of. On that map I've called [addControl()](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addcontrol) to add a [NavigationControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#navigationcontrol).

Is there a way to toggle the visibility of the NavigationControl based on the width / height of my container (which are being passed down to the container as props), much in the same way I can change the `visibility` of a layer by calling [setLayoutProperty(https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#map#setlayoutproperty)]?

I thought about adding and removing the control but per the documentation, the returned value of `addControl()` is the map itself, and I don't see any place where I can access the current controls being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward option is just to manipulate the DOM.

```
$('#map .mapbox-ctrl-top-right button').hide()
```

If you want to make that happen automatically in response to the page being resized, use CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    #map .mapbox-ctrl-top-right button {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but two problems there:

1. jQuery is not a dependency within my application. It's actually a React app.
2. Doing it through CSS doesn't really help as the map exists within a container that I am allowing my users to resize. So if my screen is 600px wide, the block holding the map may be 580px wide, or it may be 60px.

Comment: 1. youmightnotneedjquery.com. 2. You can ask a separate question for that part.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As for the "separate question", it was actually part of my original question; I guess I wasn't clear enough.

> Is there a way to toggle the visibility of the NavigationControl based on the width / height of my container (which are being passed down to the container as props)